# What protocol do networked scanners use? Linux server emulation of same?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, network-shares, scanner, print-server

TLDR:  What protocol do network scanners use, and how do I use that to set up a Linux scan server to OS X client?

---

I have a Brother DCP-7065DN laser printer/scanner.  It's great.  It's connected to the network through its native 10/100 port and we use it to print and scan from our computers (Macs running 10.8).

When we scan over the network, it goes VERY slowly because it is bottle-necked by the 10/100 network connection (100mbps is somewhere around 1/3 of the speed of USB 2.0).

That got me thinking, what if we connected it by USB to our server and set it up as a print/scan server?  The server is an Ubuntu box running 14.04 LTS, and right now it just does file and Plex serving.  I got CUPS set up beautifully for the printer side of things; then I tried to set up the scanning.

I started with SANE.  Once it was configured I was able to do local scanning just fine (quickly too!).  I installed the TWAIN-SANE interface for OS X only to discover that OS X has dismal TWAIN support.  The native Image Capture app wouldn't recognize the shared scanner.  I couldn't find a third party scanning app that would work (VueScan didn't), except for OpenOffice.  Not a convenient way to scan PDFs or images, but it proved that the sharing worked.

Anyways, this is all a long-winded way to get to my main question: what does the printer use to do it's native scanner sharing?  Whatever protocol it is works great with OS X clients with the natively bundled drivers.  Is there a way that I can emulate this from a Linux server?